# Save dictionary and persist it

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a word dictionary. I want to save the added word into the dictionary `word` so when I run it again I can lookup the added word.

```
#A DICTIONARY THAT CONTAINS ALL THE TRANSLATED WORDS
word = {"ikkje": "ikke"}

#TAKES INPUT FROM USER; THE WORD IN THE FIRST "LANGUAGE"
nynorsk = input("WRITE THE 'NYNORSKE' WORD NOW:") 

bokmål = input("WRITE THE SAME WORD IN 'BOKMÅL' NOW:")

#A FUNCTION THAT ADDS A NEW WORD WITH TRANSLATION TO THE DICTIONARY "word"
def add_word(self,var):
    word[nynorsk] = bokmål

add_word(nynorsk, bokmål)
print(word)
```

Comment: whats the issue. Your code is working fine

Comment: I need it to be saved there forever, maby something like into the file?

Comment: Ok. You should use `Pickle` for that

Comment: Use database or dump the values as JSON in a file. Dictionaries are volatile. Python has builtin functionalities to use SQLite database.

Comment: Right now your `word` dictionary is being stored in RAM. The data will be destroyed each time you run the code. Lutz Horn gave a great solution below.

Comment: You are looking for [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) . This can be anything from text file to a database. You should consider some well known [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) format, either text-based like JSON, or binary like pickle.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to persist the dictionary to a file. I recommend to use [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for this.

```
import json

#A FUNCTION THAT ADDS A NEW WORD WITH TRANSLATION TO THE DICTIONARY "word"
def add_word(nynorsk_word, bokmål_word):
    word[nynorsk_word] = bokmål_word

#A DICTIONARY THAT CONTAINS ALL THE TRANSLATED WORDS
try:
    # Try to load the word JSON file.
    word = json.load(open("word.json"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Initialize it, if the file does not exist.
    word = {"ikkje": "ikke"}

#TAKES INPUT FROM USER; THE WORD IN THE FIRST "LANGUAGE"
nynorsk = input("WRITE THE 'NYNORSKE' WORD NOW:")
bokmål = input("WRITE THE SAME WORD IN 'BOKMÅL' NOW:")

add_word(nynorsk, bokmål)

# Write the word JSON file.
with open("word.json", "w") as wordfile:
    json.dump(word, wordfile)

print(word)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this!

Comment: I added an edit. `add_word()` in the original code is using global variables, and the arguments `self` and `var` were going unused. Also, `self` is generally a keyword used in class methods, not in functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to your dictionary to persist even after you close and open your program, I may recommend two ways of doing this.

**1- You can use the `shelve` module.** This module helps you store your variables (even file objects) into a file and you can read the file afterwards.

```
import shelve

shelf = shelve.open('store')
shelf['ikkje'] = 'ikke'
```

#### Close and open file again

```
import shelve

shelf = shelve.open('store')
print(shelf['ikkje'])
# ikke
```

---

**2- You can just use `pprint.pformat` to arrange your variable into a meaningful format and save it to a *.py* file.** Afterwards just import this file and you are ready to go. Beware that you can only use this method for specific objects and not complicated objects like files.

```
import pprint

words = {'ikkje': 'ikke'}

with open('store.py', 'w') as store:
    store.write('words = ' + pprint.pformat)
```

#### Close and open file again

```
import store
print(store.words)

# {'ikkje': 'ikke'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle to store files on the local disk.It is used for serializing and de-serializing

```
temp = get_list_from_pickle('alerted_dict.pickle')
word = {"ikkje": "ikke"}
#TAKES INPUT FROM USER; THE WORD IN THE FIRST "LANGUAGE"
nynorsk = input("WRITE THE 'NYNORSKE' WORD NOW:") 
bokmål = input("WRITE THE SAME WORD IN 'BOKMÅL' NOW:")

#A FUNCTION THAT ADDS A NEW WORD WITH TRANSLATION TO THE DICTIONARY "word"
def add_word(self,var):
    word[nynorsk] = bokmål
add_word(nynorsk, bokmål)
with open('alerted_dict.pickle', 'wb') as fp:
     pickle.dump(temp, fp)
print(word)

def get_list_from_pickle(filename):
    try:
      with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
           return pickle.load(fp)
    except FileNotFoundError:
      with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
           pickle.dump([], fp)
```